# Bind DataGrid with ComboboxColumns to List

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a Dictionary which Values are used as a Source for comboboxColumn in a DataGrid. The task is the following: when user selects appropriate item from combobox Key not Value should be written to the List. 
My code:

```
        Dictionary<double, string> scores = new Dictionary<double, string>();                                   
        scores.Add(1, "the same");
        scores.Add(3, "moderate superiority");
        scores.Add(5, "strong superiority");
        scores.Add(7, "very strong superiority");
        scores.Add(9, "extremely superiority");


        //define number of alternatives
        int num = Alternatives.Children.Count - 1;

        //initialize matrix for assessment scores

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {                
            gridAssessment.Add(new double[num]);
        }

        //set initial values
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            gridAssessment[i][i] = scores.ElementAt(0).Key;                
        }

        //define source for assessment grid
        grAssessment.ItemsSource = gridAssessment;
        grAssessment.AutoGenerateColumns = false;            


        //add columns to the grid
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            DataGridComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();               
            grAssessment.Columns.Add(col);
            col.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);

            //define source for comboboxes
            col.ItemsSource = scores;                
            col.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
            col.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
            string a = "[" + i.ToString() + "]";
            Binding t = new Binding(a);
            t.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;  
            t.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;              
            col.SelectedValueBinding = t;                   
        }
```

Could you please assist me with binding? because Keys of selected values are not stored in a List :(

Comment: is there any reason why you are doing that in code instead of xaml ?

Comment: @SamTheDev because columns are added dynamically. That's why I don't code them in XAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed Dictionary to ObservableCollection and now  it works.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code and tried to re-create the UI

Code-Behind

List<double[]> gridAssessment = new List<double[]>();

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Dictionary<double, string> scores = new Dictionary<double, string>();
        scores.Add(1, "the same");
        scores.Add(3, "moderate superiority");
        scores.Add(5, "strong superiority");
        scores.Add(7, "very strong superiority");
        scores.Add(9, "extremely superiority");


        //define number of alternatives
        int num = 3;//Alternatives.Children.Count - 1;

        //initialize matrix for assessment scores

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            gridAssessment.Add(new double[num]);
        }

        //set initial values
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            gridAssessment[i][i] = scores.ElementAt(0).Key;
        }

        //define source for assessment grid
        grAssessment.ItemsSource = gridAssessment;
        grAssessment.AutoGenerateColumns = false;


        //add columns to the grid
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            DataGridComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
            grAssessment.Columns.Add(col);
            col.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);

            //define source for comboboxes
            col.ItemsSource = scores;
            col.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
            col.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
            string a = "[" + i.ToString() + "]";
            Binding t = new Binding(a);
            t.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            t.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            col.SelectedValueBinding = t;
        } 

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var c in gridAssessment)
        {
            str1.Append("<");
            foreach (var item in c)
            {
                str1.AppendFormat(" {0} ", item);    
            }
            str1.Append(">");
        }
        val.Content = str1.ToString();
    }
```

XAML

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Name="grAssessment" />
    <Button Content="Check" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" />
    <Label Name="val" Grid.Row="2"  />
</Grid>
```

I see the values as 1,2,3 displayed. If you need to set the string value, then you may need to change the List< double[] > gridAssessment = new List< double[] >()
as List< string[] > gridAssessment = new List< string[] >();
and reverse the combo's DisplayMemberPath with SelectedValuePath.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeap, predefined values are displayed correctly. But when user selects any item from combobox it's not synchronized with Source. So there is only OneWay update from Source to Target but not vice versa.

Comment: When you click on the button "Check" after selecting values from combo, does it show the proper values at label <Label Name="val" Grid.Row="2"  />